# Windows 7 with Direct Access and bridging a connection to a local RHEL VM

Tags: virtualbox, rhel6, direct-access

My company provided laptop is a Windows 7 machine configured to Microsoft Direct Access on the domain controller so that even remotely it will always be available on the domain without having to explicitly launch a VPN client.  I know that it does something with IPv6 to a remote DNS server to resolve IPv6 addresses inside the company intranet but beyond that it might as well be magic to me.  I do know that to get this to work though apparently my ISP does "IPv6 routing" and because of this our sysadmins instructed us to disable IPv6 on our laptops and for some reason that allows this all to work.  I can't pretend to understand why.

My question though is that I have been doing a proof of concept on some new software for the team, and this software is to run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5.  Since our Linux admins are nearly impossible to work with, my group typically runs an Oracle VirtualBox VM of RHEL 6.5 and sets up the Network Adapter in the VirtualBox dashboard to a Bridge Connection so that everybody in the local network can see it.  My group is in a different office with its own router so everybody in our LAN is able to ping my local VM and SSH into it so they can play around.  That router then has a hardware VPN tunnel into the greater WAN so people in other offices are also able to do the same.

When I am working from home however, the RHEL VM will instead get its IP address from my home router.  The weird thing is that with Direct Access that while I can resolve domain names and connect to machine names in the domain, local IP addresses in my offices LAN are not reachable.  So they can't reach me obviously and I can't reach them.

I was wondering if I perhaps set a static IP and then set eth0 to the netmask and gateway address of the offices LAN router but then I can't even ping it from home.  Does anybody have any ideas on if it is possible to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Direct Access works you'd have to create a DNS address internally pointed at your VirtualBox.
No amount of static configuration will allow you to reach your VirtualBox while connected solely through DA.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just wanted somebody who understands Direct Access a bit better to say this.